# Android only provides right results when debugging

Tags: android, debugging, listview, arraylist

I started developing on Android

**When I run the program in Debugging mode, I always get the right result, but when I started running i get just the static values (not those retrieved from server).**

Here is my Class :

```
public class ListFromSql extends Activity
{
    ListView lv;
    TextView tv;
    String message_info="";
    JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();
    private static String url_updateData = "http://myserver/getfrom_sqlserver.php";
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";
    private ArrayList<String> your_array_list = new ArrayList<String>();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);                
        setContentView(R.layout.main);              
        new ConnectToPhp().execute();
        ArrayList<String> your_array_list2 = new ArrayList<String>();
        your_array_list2 = PrepareList();

        for(int k=0;k<5;k++)
        {
            int num=5-k;
            your_array_list2.add("TestListView " + num);
        }

        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            this, 
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            your_array_list2 );
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewFromDB);
        lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    }

    private ArrayList PrepareList()
    {
        ArrayList todoItems = new ArrayList();  
        todoItems=your_array_list;
        todoItems.add("First Line Test");
        return todoItems;                
    }

    private void populateListViewFromDB(String elements)
    {
        String attributes[]=elements.split("=>");           
        your_array_list.add(attributes[1]);
    }

    private class ConnectToPhp extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>
    {
        protected String doInBackground(String... url)
        {
            try
            {      
                String deviceIdtxt="";
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id_device",deviceIdtxt));
                JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_updateData, "POST", params);
                Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

                try
                {
                    int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                    if (success == 1)
                    {
                        message_info="La synchronisation a été faite avec succès";
                        String message=json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
                        int counter = 0;
                        for( int i=0; i<message.length(); i++ )
                        {
                            if( message.charAt(i) == ',' )
                            {
                                counter++;
                            }
                        }
                        if(counter>0)
                        {
                            String str[]=message.split(",");
                            for( int j=0; j<counter; j++ )
                            {
                                populateListViewFromDB(str[j]);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else if (success == 2)
                    {
                        message_info="Serveur indisponible!";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        message_info="Problème lors de la synchronisation! ";
                    }
                }
                catch (JSONException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return "";
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

If you need additional information, please ask!

Thank you in advance

Comment: Have you tried running the php stand alone to validate it's returning what you expect?

Comment: @rrirower yes it retrieves all the data

Comment: You may benefit from a refresher [tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_php_mysql.htm).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems:

1. thread safety! Update UI data from `onPostExecute` method
2. update data using ArrayAdapter not array itself

Comment: the same problem even from onPostExecute method

Answer (score 0):

When you run things in your debugger, you don't get full multithreading.  It looks ok, because things are not occurring in parallel but in serial.  I think your app have some parts operating on data that may be getting stepped on, overwritten, etc within your background task when you're not debugging.

Try to separate the true background tasks from database or other things and do those in onPostExecute()

Comment: the same problem even from onPostExecute method